# Unable to read image files from sdcard in phonegap: android

Tags: android, cordova

I am a phonegap newbie. I am trying to read and image file from sdcard in android using
phonegap official tutorial. The problem is that the image is not being displayed instead a question mark appears in its place.

My Code:

```
var pictureSource;  
var destinationType;  


document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);


function onDeviceReady(){ 

   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="onready about to request";
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, onFail);}





function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("1.jpg", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);

}

function readDataUrl(file) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);

    };  
    document.getElementById("smallImage").style.display='block'; 
    document.getElementById("smallImage").src = reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}



function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}



</script>
```

edit:
Using API 16 and min-sdk8
"smallImage" is a  tag it's working fine with onphotodatasuccess. So, camera is not a problem here. Everything related to camera functions is ok. Reading from sdcard is posing a problem at the assignment statement.
document.getElementById("smallImage").src = reader.readAsDataURL(file); if I add this i get the string and unknown chromium error -6, else i see the usual image converted string.
Thanks

Comment: add alert in your `onPhotoDataSuccess` method for `imageURI` and `smallImage` after initialization. And paste both the values here.

Comment: @PratikSharma: the onPhotoDataSuccess is working fine. I added alert("success"); to my code but it doesn't seem to have any visual effect. My logging events, however, are working fine and display a long character string of the image with lines specified from my code:console.log("Read as data URL");
            console.log(evt.target.result);

Comment: adding document.getElementById("smallImage").src = reader.readAsDataURL(file); generates an error "Unknown chromium error: -6" which i can't fathom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a working example :

EDITED:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pick Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, onFail);
    }

     function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("1.jpg", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        readDataUrl(file);  
    }

    function readDataUrl(file) {
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
           console.log("Read as data URL");
           console.log(evt.target.result);
           document.getElementById("smallImage").style.display='block'; 
           document.getElementById("smallImage").src = evt.target.result;   
        }; 
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function fail(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

This will allow you to pick any specified image from sdcard.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: This code is meant for the camera. I am trying to read, as you can see, from the memory by giving image names like "1.jpg". Again, Camera is working fine including imageUri etc. It's the reading from memory that doesn't seem to have any effect. Also, in my case, smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData; didn't work either.

Comment: what do you need exactly? do you need to capture image from camera or from gallery?  and what is the need of "1.jpg", I dont get that.

Comment: As I have mentioned,I don't need to read from camera. I am just trying to use the filesystem api and read a file from the /mnt/sdcard. I wish to read all images that are there in the sdcard irrespective of the folder they are in. This was just a trial read. 1.jpg is added by me in my sdcard folder.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? This works for the same. It will allow you to select image from the gallery and set the image div. It is not for opening camera.

Comment: Ok, I got it, you are trying to read from Photolibrary. But my need is to use the filesystem api. I have edited the script and removed onphotodatasuccess etc...leaving only the filesystem code in order remove any confusion. Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: I posted edited solution and it can pick "1.jpg" file from my sdcard and set in the image div.

Comment: @PratikSharma  Excuse me, if I have lots of pictures to read. Will it cost lots of time? And if the picture is at sdcard/story/img/pic_1.jpg, should I write `fileSystem.root.getFile("story/img/pic_1.jpg", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);` to access? I mean is the path correct?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady(){ 
  //This file have to exist
  var location= "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141105_124208.jpg";
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(location, function(oFile) {
    oFile.file(function(readyFile) {
      var reader= new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend= function(evt) {
        document.getElementById("smallImage").style.display='block'; 
        document.getElementById("smallImage").src = evt.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(readyFile); 
    });
  }, function(err){
    console.log('### ERR: filesystem.directoryUp() - ' + (JSON.stringify(err)));
});

</script>
```