# How to move file to app directory using Cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-file, cordova-4

How can I move the image captured from my phone camera to the Cordova app directory?

I want to move the file to, ideally with mkdir like function for new directories

```
app/www/uploads/new
```

The image location of the file is saved in a var:

```
imagePath = file://emu/0/android/cache/something.jpg
```

Any help is welcomed.

I am using Cordova version 4.1.2 and installed the Cordova File Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I do think that the `app/www` directory is read-only since it contains your actual code and is packaged as *.apk*. Why would you need it there though? It is still since it is on disk. If you want to copy it for your own applications data partition, you should use the *File plugin* that you already mentioned to move it under *cordova.file.externalDataDirectory* or some other place you wish to move it.

**Update**

Since you want to show the file as image on HTML, the easiest way is to read it as *Data URL* (base64 format) and give that as *src* for image instead of path for file like this

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, onFail);}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("<your_image_file>.jpg", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);

        var imageData = evt.target.result;
        document.getElementById("img#image1").src = imageData;
    };  
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); // Read as Data URL (base64)
}
```

The structure for that code is borrowed from the [Pratik Sharma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858015/unable-to-read-image-files-from-sdcard-in-phonegap-android) and it may not completely work for your case but you should be able to pick up the idea from there. It relies on that you have this kind of image tag available on your HTML.

```
<img id="image1" src="" />
```

If you want to read more about this, consult [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) Wikipedia article.

Comment: ok thanks, so if I save it in the externalDataDirectory, can I display the image with html5? I didn't know how to display the image otherwise. If I could move it to www/uploads/new.. I could do something like <img src="uploads/new/something.jpg" />, because then I won't need absolute paths.

Comment: this is cross-platform applicable right? and do you maybe have an example code? :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll wait for some other solutions. I do think this might work.. but performance wise, I don't think this is the best solution, since a user can have over 50 images.

Comment: You anyway do need at least the absolute paths and to play with those on correct formats. And it is somewhat cross-platform but referring to local images has proven to be hard and that is why for example we did just convert every image to Data URI. We have approximately 5 to 50 images on each page and there has been no performance problem whatsoever nor should there be. I do although understand your hesitation about that. I did have it too when exploring this.. :)