# Cordova FileUpload API returns error code 3

Tags: android, cordova, file-upload, ibm-mobilefirst

I am having problem trying to upload an image file to my local web server (hosted using wampserver) for android hybrid app built using IBM Worklight 6.2.0 with Cordova version 3.4.0. The code snippet is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  // Wait for Cordova to load
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  // Cordova is ready
  function onDeviceReady() {
    // Nothing here
  }

  function getImage() {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
      alert('get picture failed');
    }, {
      quality: 40,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    });

  }

  function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://192.168.1.4:8081/folder_name/upload2.php"), win, fail, options);
  }

  function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    alert(r.response);
  }

  function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
  }
</script>

<button onclick="getImage();">Upload a Photo</button>
```

upload2.php

```
<?php print_r($_FILES); $new_image_name="namethisimage.jpg" ; move_uploaded_file($_FILES[ "file"][ "tmp_name"], "folder_name/uploads/".$new_image_name); ?>
```

I'm getting http status 200 and an error code 3. Besides that, I also getting this error below the http status and error code error.

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:14584 from pid=4926, uid=10092 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()

Is there any solution to this? Or is there a better way for me to upload the image file?

I've added the following to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: 1) the deviceready call is not required; Worklight does this for you internally, otherwise the app would not function at all.

Comment: 2) Make sure you've added android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"

Comment: @IdanAdar Forgot to mention that I've already added the MANAGE_DOCUMENTS permission in AndroidManifest.xml. I have removed the deviceready call, it still returning error code 3.

Comment: Yes, it's just not needed, that is all. The issue does not seem to be originating from Worklight here.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably from either cordova or with my web server. I have found out that the meaning of server code error 3 is _Permission denied: The user does not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation_ as seen from [here](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/sftp_codes). Not sure about what the real problem is thou. I have tried directly accessing an image file in my web server using `<img>` tag with AngularJS `ng-src` and the image can be shown on the page in my mobile.

Comment: My suggestion for you is to create a new application, w/out angularJS, etc - just the file image upload and see if it works. Start isolating your project

Comment: I have isolate the upload code to another project and it does works. Not sure what's the problem here... hmm...

Comment: I have do some testing and find out that we will need to choose the photos from Gallery instead of direct from sdcard path, or else it will return error. Not sure what prevent us from choosing the sdcard path.

Comment: Maybe this will help to read from sd card: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858015/unable-to-read-image-files-from-sdcard-in-phonegap-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what's the issue here. My code just works suddenly, even with AngularJS. I will just share my working code here, if others might want to refer.

main.js

```
$scope.getImage = function() {
             // Retrieve image file location from specified source
             navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, function(message) {
                alert('get picture failed');
            },{
                quality: 50, 
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            }
             );
         }

        function onSuccess(imageURI) {
            $scope.image = imageURI;
        };

         function uploadPhoto(image) {

             var options = new FileUploadOptions();
             options.fileKey="file";
             options.fileName= $scope.imageName;
             options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

             var params = new Object();
             params.value1 = "test";
             params.value2 = "param";

             options.params = params;
             options.chunkedMode = false;

             var ft = new FileTransfer();
             ft.upload(image, encodeURI(ipaddress_to_your_server/root_folder/upload.php), win, fail, options);
         }

         function win(r) {
             console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
             console.log("Response = " + r.response);
             console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
             alert(r.response);
         }

         function fail(error) {
             alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
         }
```

upload.php

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
$image_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$image_name);
?>
```

You will just need to call the `$scope.getImage` function in html to open the device's photo library.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last image, it seems that you solved this somehow - you should share it as an answer.

Regardless,

1. Why is there PHP code in your code snippet? Is this code snippet originating from your Worklight-based app? You cannot have there PHP... This is a mobile app, running in your device, not on your server. There is nothing there that will interpret that code.
2. The following should not be used in your app, because Cordova is part of the Worklight framework and this check is done internally. Instead, your code should sit inside the wlCommonInit() function in main.js, or be called from there.

   ```
   // Wait for Cordova to load
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

   // Cordova is ready
   function onDeviceReady() {
       // Nothing here
   }
   ```

I suspect that is why nothing works for you. Try to use AJAX to make the request to the server, to receive the sent image and store it in your web server.

Comment: The PHP code is actually my upload script that will be called by the `ft.upload()` function. Already edited it in my question. Thanks for the heads up.